# Angular: Run some JQuery against a selection of views

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I already wrote the code to do this, but the way I did it felt *so* inelegant I just had to ask if someone had some basic advice for me. Basically I want to run some JQuery to modify the attributes of buttons in a sub-set of views (they're all in the same directory). I wrote the JQuery to do this but *I cannot figure out where to put this code*.

Right now I'm just shoving a .js file in to those views' directory and using an include statement toward the end of each view file. Not exactly MVC......

## Situation

several buttons appear in the interface with no visible label. All the info about them is in a `popover` attribute. This is fine (or maybe it's bad UI or whatever) as long as you're not blind and using a screen-reader, which won't pick up this popover text. I want to copy the contents of the popover text to an `aria-label`

## adding labels "manually"

Right now the button in question is created within an Angular framework. The Jade for the button looks like this:

```
button.customize-option(class='Pet_Egg_{{::egg}}',
   ng-class='{selectableInventory: selectedPotion && !(user.items.pets[egg+"-"+selectedPotion.key]>0) && (Content.dropEggs[egg] || !selectedPotion.premium)}',
   popover-title!=env.t("egg", {eggType: "{{::Content.eggs[egg].text()}}"}),
   popover-trigger='mouseenter', popover-placement='right')
```

(tried to simplify it from the production version) If I wanted to just add an aria-label to this button I could modify it like so:

```
button.customize-option(class='Pet_Egg_{{::egg}}',
    ng-class='{selectableInventory: selectedPotion && !(user.items.pets[egg+"-"+selectedPotion.key]>0) && (Content.dropEggs[egg] || !selectedPotion.premium)}',
    popover-title!=env.t("egg", {eggType: "{{::Content.eggs[egg].text()}}"}),
    aria-label!=env.t("egg", {eggType: "{{::Content.eggs[egg].text()}}"}),
    popover-trigger='mouseenter', popover-placement='right')
```

And that works great, buuuuuut there are several dozen other buttons all created with similar but not-identical code. I was adding this aria-label line several dozen times. That felt... inelegant. So I wrote some JQuery!

## adding labels "automatically"

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("button[popover]").each(function(){
    var text = $(this).attr('popover');
    //not everything has a popover-title. If it does we want that title for the aria-label
    if ($(this).attr('popover-title') !== undefined){
      var title = $(this).attr('popover-title');
      $(this).attr('aria-label', title);
    } else {
      //fall back to just using the popover text if no title is present
      $(this).attr('aria-label', text);
    }
  });
  //turns out some of the popovers are on divs which hold the button
  $("div[popover]").each(function(){
    var label = "";
    if ($(this).attr('popover-title') !== undefined){
      label = $(this).attr('popover-title');
    } else {
      label = $(this).attr('popover');
    }
    $(this).find("button").attr('aria-label', label);
  })
});
```

I was pretty proud of myself! It went from many many lines of code changes across the views to this one short, readable JS file.

## Where does that JS go???!?!?

I admit to being an Angular neophyte, but essentially none of the spots I could find made sense for adding this code. The closes I came was a view  in `shared/` for the footer. I could add the script there and it would run on *every* route for the app. That's how someone had done the analytics footer already. But there were two problems with this approach:

1. Not every page/route/view needs this `aria-label` fix. Most buttons on the site have readable labels. I could add checks to make sure I didn't overwrite an existing `aria-label` but it would still mean this script was running unnecessarily
2. I'm not certain that every view has popover text or a popover-title that will work as an `aria-label`

So, that's where I stand. I'm not certain if a custom controller (?) or something is the best approach to resolve this.

If you want to take a look at the project (without my changes) [this is the folder of 'views'](https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitrpg/tree/develop/website/views/options/inventory) where I would be dumping the .js file and adding an `include` statement to every view.

Comment: what should be done is create a directive ...then within directive each element instance is exposed as jQuery object (when JQuery in page before angular) or jQlite object when jQuery not present. *`document.ready`* is generally worthless in angular pages

Comment: Put it in a `.run` block -- [AngularJS Developers Guide -- Run Blocks](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#run-blocks) and [AngularJS angular.module API Reference -- run](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the same thing in AngularJS, create a custom directive to add the `aria-label` attribute to your popovers.

## Add Labels Automatically

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('popover', function () {
    return function(scope,elem,attrs) {
        var text, title, label ;
        if (elem[0].tagName == "BUTTON") {
            text = attrs.popover;
            if (attrs.popoverTitle) {
                title = attrs.popoverTitle;
                attrs.$set('ariaLabel', title);
            } else {
                attrs.$set('ariaLabel', text);
            };
            console.log(elem[0]);
        };
        if (elem[0].tagName == "DIV") {
            label = "";
            if (attrs.popoverTitle) {
                label = attrs.popoverTitle;
            } else {
                label = attrs.popover;
            }
            var button = elem.find("button");
            button.attr('aria-label', label);
            console.log(button[0]);
        };
    };
});
```

The [DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b65xjgn8/).

Comment: This was very helpful! I haven't tried it in the context of this app yet, but def. shows the right approach, thank you!